# "@Output" decorator doesn't emit event if "event.stopPropagation()" called

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-components

I have one main component and one child

```
<main>
     <child 
        [nodes]="nodes" 
        (nodeChanged)="someFunction(output)">
     </child>
<main>
```

Child component renders multilevel tree structure recursively (i.e. it renders itself if there are children) in which every node is clickable, irrespective of it is terminal node or not.

In child component every node has a click event registered "clickedNode()". Now because I don't want my click event to bubble up to clicked node's head I wrote "event.stopPropagation()" in "clickedNode()" function.

```
@Output() nodeChanged = new EventEmitter<Object>();

clickedNode(selectedNode, e:MouseEvent){
    this.nodeChanged.emit(selectedNode);
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Now the problem is `@output emitter` doesn't if inner level of component gets clicked. It emits only if level one nodes are clicked.

Comment: I can guess only 1 reason for that, `e` is not defined at some point and `clickedNode` crashes. Check the console. `@Output` and mouse events are not connected to each other at all.

Comment: is selectedNode actually the event being passed in by your method? Try removing the first parameter passed into your clickedNode method     
 clickedNode( e:MouseEvent) - you aren't actually passing a node into the method you are calling

Comment: @David `(click)="clickedNode(node, $event)"` selectedNode is the value I am passing from html i.e. node object which got clicked

Comment: @David Html is of parent component and "clickedNode" function is written in child component. I have edited the question to make it clear

Comment: Just taking a stab but....  Call `stopPropogation()` before you call `this.nodeChanged.emit(selectedNode)`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement two click method for it.One is for `stopPrapogation` and another one is for `EventEmitter`

**HTML**

```
<div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (click)="clickedNode(<data you want to pass>)"> 
</div>
```

**TS**

```
@Output() nodeChanged = new EventEmitter<Object>();

clickedNode(selectedNode){
    this.nodeChanged.emit(selectedNode);
}
```

I hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is that in the HTML you are passing one value and this function expects to receive two values. If you want to access to the node clicked you can do it through the event by itself

Comment: Html is of parent component and "clickedNode" function is written in child component. I have edited the question to make it clear

Comment: Then we need the code from the child to be sure you are doing well in the event declaration in the child component HTML